# Passing Data Between ViewControllers in Swift using segue

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, segue, viewcontroller

I have a problem with the code that works perfectly in the tutorial that I am watching. I saw that in the tutorial they are using Swift 1 and I think I have Swift 2.
 the first viewcontroler:

```
    import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textfield1: UITextField!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var DestViewController : ViewTwo = segue.destinationViewController as ViewTwo  // here is where I get the error

    }
```

What should I change?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
var DestViewController : ViewTwo = segue.destinationViewController as ViewTwo  // here is where I get the error
```

Would need to be

```
var destViewController : ViewTwo = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewTwo  // here is where I get the error
```

Notice `!as` but this could crash as its `Force unwrapping` the destination view as `ViewTwo` when in the future it may not be.

replace with

```
if let destViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? ViewTwo {
    //Do stuff to the destination controller here
}
```

Comment: Can you please mark as the answer, thanks!